# what difference does arranging a navbar as an unordered list makes in HTML?

Tags: html

I came accross a navbar while learning HTML, I'm not sure why the person who coded it made it as.

I also want to know why his his "Products" dropdown menu has an unordered list nested in it? are there any alternative to this?

here is the code:

```
<nav>  
    <ul>  
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>

        <li>  
            <a href="#">Products</a>  
            <ul>  
                <li><a href="#">Engineering</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">Telecom</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">Energy</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">Finance</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">Consultancy</a></li>  
            </ul>  
        </li>  

        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>  
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>  
    </ul>  
</nav>
```

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/are-navigation-lists-necessary/

Comment: Of course you can make every element in your layout a `<div>`. Distinguishing hundreds of nested `<div>`s is so much easier, right? Think about semantics: a navigation bar is like a list of links and the order doesn’t matter for the content (only for the layout), so an unordered list is used.

Comment: @j08691 your comment makes the best answer, thanks alot

Answer (score 3):

It is marked up as a list because the content is a list of links. It is unordered because the order of the links does not particularly matter (compare to a novel where you need to read the chapters in order for them to make sense). That's simply what it is, so the markup describes it.

Likewise, the list of links to products is a list, so the markup says it is a list.

As for alternatives… there are no good ones. HTML is supposed to describe the semantics of the content it is marking up, and these are lists of links.